# How to terminate python program with given signal?

Tags: python, operating-system, return-value

In C, I'd do something like

```
int main() {
    return 42;
}
```

and after executing the program, I can(in Linux) prompt `echo $?` to the console to get the desired `42` as the return signal from the last operation. How can I do that in python?

I tried just creating a file with a `return 42` in it, but it says that it is not inside a function(obviously).

Comment: [sys.exit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit), or the newer [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html#module-atexit)

Answer (score 2):

exit(42)

will give you the desired behaviour.